# How to pass an object property as a parameter?

Tags: javascript, parameters, properties, arguments, javascript-objects

I've been trying to find this out for a while now.

I need to write a function that takes the value of a property through a parameter. This would minimize the code I'd have to write by a lot. It's a function belonging to a game loop (called once every second)

The function just takes a number and divide it by a pre determined number and then adds the corresponding letter behind the number ( 1.000 would become 1k)

The game uses a lot of numbers and for a bout 9 out of 10 numbers i'd like to do this.

Example:

```
function Truncate (object, rss, idtr, idtr1, idtr2) {
var n1 = 1000;
var n2 = 1000000;
var n3 = 1000000000;
var n4 = 1000000000000;

if ( rss == "gas" ){ var a1 =    object.currentgas;
   if  (a1 < n1) {
          trunkholdergas = a1;
           document.getElementById(idtr).innerHTML = " "; }
  else if (a1 >= n1 && a1 < n2) {
        trunkholdergas = a1 / n1;   
            document.getElementById(idtr).innerHTML = "k"; }
```

I call this line in the loop:

```
Truncate (Player, 'gas', 'trunkgas');
```

Since I used a work around I made an if statement system, so my function knows what to do with what I give it. This works but I have to specify everything exactly where i'd rather pass the property directly.

I also found that if I give a variable as a parameter that it won't allow me to initialize it's value. Meaning I also have to specify the variables that hold the changing values for each case.

Like this didn't work:

```
Truncate (Player, 'gas', 'trunkgas', vari);


 if ( rss == "gas" ){ var a1 = object.currentgas;
       if  (a1 < n1) {
              vari = a1;
         document.getElementById(idtr).innerHTML = " "; }
```

Am I just doing this wrong or are these javascripts limitations?

I'm looking for a pure javascript solution as that is what i'm currently learning.

EDIT: problem has been solved. For people who need a similar function in his/her project here is the code:

```
function Truncate (object,  idtr, idtr1) {
var n1 = 1000;
   var n2 = 1000000;
   var n3 = 1000000000;
   var n4 = 1000000000000;

  var a1 = object;
   var trunkholder = 0;

  if  (a1 < n1) {
              trunkholder = a1;
         document.getElementById(idtr).innerHTML = " "; 
         document.getElementById(idtr1).innerHTML = trunkholder.toFixed(2); }
      else if (a1 >= n1 && a1 < n2) {
            var b = a1 / n1;
            trunkholder = b;   
         document.getElementById(idtr).innerHTML = "k"; 
         document.getElementById(idtr1).innerHTML = trunkholder.toFixed(2);}
     else if(a1 >= n2 && a1 < n3) {
            var c = a1 / n2;   
            trunkholder = c;
         document.getElementById(idtr).innerHTML = "m"; 
         document.getElementById(idtr1).innerHTML = trunkholder.toFixed(2);}
     else if (a1 >= n3 && a1 < n4){
            var d = a1 / n3;
            trunkholder = d;
            document.getElementById(idtr).innerHTML = "b"; 
            document.getElementById(idtr1).innerHTML = trunkholder.toFixed(2);}
        else if ( a1 >= n4 ) {
              var e = a1 / n4; 
              trunkholder = e;
           document.getElementById(idtr).innerHTML = "t"; 
           document.getElementById(idtr1).innerHTML = trunkholder.toFixed(2);} 
};
```

Calling the function:

```
Truncate (Player.currentgas, 'trunkgas', 'currentgas');
```

It takes the value of the specified property and the id names of the elements I used to show the number and corresponding letter. It only uses 2 variables to store both the original and modified number, which is directly passed to the interface. So that you can call it an unlimited amount of times.

Hope this can be of use to someone!

Comment: It sounds like you need to modularize your function so it does one thing. If the function 'just takes a number', then it should have one argument. Make simple, reusable functions with one job and a lot of these problems go away.

Comment: In order to do so I need the property of an object as a parameter... What you describe is exactly what i'm trying to archieve. And 'just a number' was simplified. If you read more care fully you'd know that it would be divided by another number after being checked for it's value as to choose the correct value.

Right now i indeed dont have a modular function. Hence i'm asking these questions.

Comment: In other words how can I pass object.itsproperty as opossed to passing the object itself to manipulate it's value inside a function. I need that property because it decides which number will be changed. (The other parameters merely indicate which elements to change.

Comment: You can pass an object's property into a function by just passing the property: `someFunction(object.property)`, but if that property is a simple value (as opposed to another object) manipulating it in the function won't manipulate the original object.

Comment: I just tried your example again and now it works mark I must have done something wrong earlier... Lol. I only need the property it's value because for the script, the source of the value doesn't matter. I basically store it in a var with which I do the math. This is so that the numbers behind the "screen" are unaffected and thus not messing up any math. The function simply takes  the given value. Does what it should do and update that value to a global variable which are shown on screen with another function However now I should be able to make it work like I intended! Thank you Sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question, but it is possible to pass a JavaScript object property to a function. You can use `Object.keys()` to get a list of properties contained by the object, and send the string value to a function. You can read more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys.

If you mean passing the value of that object's property then it is as simple as `object["property"]` or `object.property`

Comment: Thank you! Mark just clarified it for me. I was led to the assumption that object.property wasn't possible. Due to it not working in my code earlier (Error on my side I geuss) and when googling the matter I just got more confused.